# Tailwind CSS no crea las carpetas en mi proyecto

Tags: nodejs, npm, tailwind

Estoy tratando de instalar **Tailwind** y por más que esté en la carpeta correcta, el comando:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
```

Al finalizar no crea la carpeta node_modules ni los .json, me tira el los siguientes mensajes en consola.

```
up to date, audited 95 packages in 936ms

21 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Parece haber finalizado con éxito pero no puedo proseguir mi proyecto si no tengo esas carpetas. Instalé y desinstale varias veces node.js pero tampoco, probé con las dos versiones disponibles para windows y tampoco, probé hacerlo directo al comando desde vscode en la carpeta pero igual sigue sin funcionar. Reinicie la pc varias veces y tampoco.

La ruta está correcta y he probado varias veces con distintas pero parece no crear nada, es raro ya que hace unas semana no sucedía. Quizá sea un error muy de novato pero en serio que no veo el problema. Si a alguien se le da de vista el problema y me ayuda en serio que muchas gracias :D

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema.... Lograste solucionar?

Comment: Es posible que el problema se deba a que no se ha inicializado el proyecto de Node.js en el que estás trabajando. Para instalar Tailwind CSS en un proyecto de Node.js, debes asegurarte de que Node.js esté instalado en tu sistema y que hayas inicializado tu proyecto de Node.js con npm init. Luego, puedes instalar Tailwind CSS como una dependencia de desarrollo utilizando el siguiente comando: npm install tailwindcss --save-dev

Comment: Además de lo que dice pcandido, si tu projecto está en alguna subcarpeta de un proyecto más arriba, puede que instale todos los módulos en ese proyecto padre.